What kind of benefit is there in being allowed to tie woolen strings onto a linen garment?
The Midrash Tanchuma (Shemini 8:2) says as follows:

שֶׁלֹּא יַטְעֶךָ יִצְרְךָ לוֹמַר, שֶׁכָּל דְּבָרִים טוֹבִים אָסַר
הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְיִשְׂרָאֵל, אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא,
כָּל מַה שֶּׁאָסַרְתִּי לְךָ, הִתַּרְתִּי לְךָ כְּנֶגְדוֹ. כֵּיצַד,
אָסַרְתִּי לְךָ דַּם נִדָּה, הִתַּרְתִּי לְךָ דַּם בְּתוּלִים.
אָסַרְתִּי לְךָ אֶת הַדָּם, הִתַּרְתִּי לְךָ אֶת הַכָּבֵד שֶׁכֻּלּוֹ
דָּם. אָסַרְתִּי לְךָ אֶת הַחֲזִיר, הִתַּרְתִּי לְךָ אֶת הַדָּג
שֶׁשְּׁמוֹ שִׁבּוּטָא, שֶׁהוּא דּוֹמֶה לַחֲזִיר. אָסַרְתִּי לְךָ
אֵשֶׁת אִישׁ, הִתַּרְתִּי לְךָ גְּרוּשַׁת אִישׁ. אָסַרְתִּי לְךָ
נָכְרִית, הִתַּרְתִּי לְךָ אֵשֶׁת יְפַת תֹּאַר. אָסַרְתִּי לְךָ אֵשֶׁת
אָח, הִתַּרְתִּי לְךָ יְבָמָה לְאַחַר מִיתָתוֹ בְּלֹא בָּנִים,
שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: יְבָמָהּ יָבֹא עָלֶיהָ (דברים כה, ה). אָסַרְתִּי לְךָ
כִּלְאַיִם, הִתַּרְתִּי לְךָ סָדִין בְּצִיצִית.
Lest your [evil] drive lead you astray, saying that the Holy One,
blessed be He, has forbidden Israel from having good things, the Holy
One, blessed be He, said, “Whatever I have forbidden you from having,
I have permitted you to have [something] that corresponds to it. How
is this? I have forbidden you menstrual blood; I have permitted you
virginal blood. I have forbidden you [animal] blood; I have permitted
you the liver, which is wholly blood. I have forbidden you the flesh
of swine; I have permitted you the tongue of a fish with the name
shibbuta, which resembles swine. I have forbidden you [another] man's
wife; I have permitted you a man’s divorcee. I have forbidden a
gentile woman; I have permitted a beautiful woman [captive]. I have
forbidden you a brother's wife; I have permitted her for you after his
death, with no children, as stated (in Deut. 25:5), ‘her
brother-in-law shall have sexual intercourse with her.’ I have
forbidden you mingled seeds, but I have permitted you a sindon with a
woolen fringe.

Question: what benefit is there in being allowed to tie woolen strings onto a linen garment?

Clothiers do use wool and linen in the same garment so they obviously find a benefit in doing so. Ask one.

Wool absorbs dye far, far better than linen. Techelet doesn't just mean any-fabric-dyed-with-the-special-aquatic-blue, it means wool dyed that way.
So from a strictly halachic perspective, the only way to get the full mitzvah of tzitzis if one has a linen garment is to tie on techelet-dyed-wool strings.
I think that's really all there is to it ... but I suppose from a strictly aesthetic perspective, I imagine such strings add a splash of color.
